# how to call a c++ file from python without using any of the spam bindings?

Tags: python

i have this encryption algorithm written in C++ , but the values that has to be encrypted are being taken input and stored in a file by a python program . Thus how can i call this c++ program from python?

Answer (score 2):

Look for the `subprocess` module.  It is the recommended way to invoke processes from within Python.  The `os.system` function is a viable alternative sometimes, if your needs are very simple (no pipes, simple arguments, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The `os.system` function will invoke an arbitrary command-line from python.